# Set background color in Phaser

Tags: color, phaser

I want to set a background color for my game.

I found this solution:

```
function create() {
  this.cameras.main.setBackgroundColor("#d5d5d5");
}
```

but I want to be sure that there is not a more standard way to do this, because editing the camera's property means that the background would be different for another camera.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `backgroundColor` property of the `GameConfig` when you create a new `Phaser.Game`.

```js
const config = {
   // ...
   backgroundColor: '#d5d5d'
}

const game = new Phaser.Game(config)
```

Phaser docs for more info: https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.Core.html#.GameConfig